# want to delete debug level logs (log4j)

Tags: java, log4j

I am new in log4j.I am stuck in log4j log level.My case is that i have created web service server where i print the soap request and response .Although i got the soap ui request and response in trace level ,but my question is that i want to delete all the debug level logs but my request print in trace level which is above the debug level.if i take `rootLogger=trace` ,then only i see the soap request and response and debug level logs. but if i use other level as rootLogger ,then i could not see trace level logs.I want to remove debug level logs and retain trace level..

My Log4j.properties :

```
log4j.rootCategory=Trace, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%c{3}] %m%n



LOGS :
DEBUG [javaguys.webservices.UserServiceEndpoints] dafa

DEBUG [method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor] Marshalling [com.javaguys.webservices.getuserservices.GetUserResponse@39178c5c] to response payload

DEBUG [endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor] Response: <ns3:GetUserResponse xmlns:ns3="http://com/javaguys/webservices/getUserServices" xmlns:ns2="http://user.javaguys.blog.com"><ns3:userDetails><ns2:UserId>1</ns2:UserId><ns2:UserName>ashish</ns2:UserName><ns2:UserGender>M</ns2:UserGender><ns2:UserStatus>True</ns2:UserStatus></ns3:userDetails></ns3:GetUserResponse>

DEBUG [endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor] Response message validated
TRACE [server.MessageTracing.sent] Sent response [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns3:GetUserResponse xmlns:ns2="http://user.javaguys.blog.com" xmlns:ns3="http://com/javaguys/webservices/getUserServices"><ns3:userDetails><ns2:UserId>1</ns2:UserId><ns2:UserName>ashish</ns2:UserName><ns2:UserGender>M</ns2:UserGender><ns2:UserStatus>True</ns2:UserStatus></ns3:userDetails></ns3:GetUserResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>] for request [<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:get="http://com/javaguys/webservices/getUserServices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <get:GetUserRequest>
         <get:userId>1</get:userId>
      </get:GetUserRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>]

DEBUG [transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] Successfully completed request
```

Is there any way to remove debug level logs?

Comment: Upload your java code where you are using logger and you can modified your code there....you can call only specific level of logger.

Comment: This is very strange requirement. When you set root level TRACE all lower statements as DEBUG are logged as well. Set low lvl for root e.g. ERROR and TRACE for components you expect the issue